# Spark DataFrame - Remove Rows with logic

Tags: scala, apache-spark, functional-programming, apache-spark-sql

I need a help with the next case:

I have the next DataFrame
[image]

I need remove the rows repeat by `CNTA_TIPODOCUMENTOS` and CNTA_NRODOCUMENTO and order by the last `CNTA_FECHA_FORMULARIO`, for instance in the `CNTA_NRODOCUMENTO`  `35468731`. I should get this row.

```
|                  1|         35468731| 2012-08-25 00:00:...|              MARIA|
```

Do you have any ideas about that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to use `Window` function `row_number` to order the properly partitioned date in descending order and pick only the first row per partition:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, 80025709, "2010-07-19 00:00:00", "JUAN"),
  (1, 35468731, "2010-07-28 00:00:00", "PEDRO"),
  (1, 51714038, "2010-08-02 00:00:00", "ALEX"),
  (1, 35468731, "2011-09-28 00:00:00", "KAREN"),
  (1, 35468731, "2012-08-25 00:00:00", "MARIA")
).toDF("c1", "c2", "date", "name")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

df.withColumn(
    "rownum",
    row_number.over(Window.partitionBy($"c1", $"c2").orderBy($"date".desc))
  ).
  select($"c1", $"c2", $"date", $"name").
  where($"rownum" === 1).
  show

// +---+--------+-------------------+-----+
// | c1|      c2|               date| name|
// +---+--------+-------------------+-----+
// |  1|51714038|2010-08-02 00:00:00| ALEX|
// |  1|80025709|2010-07-19 00:00:00| JUAN|
// |  1|35468731|2012-08-25 00:00:00|MARIA|
// +---+--------+-------------------+-----+
```